# Retrofit methods do not execute

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an Android client and a Rest API built with ASP Web API. My problem is only in one request, the `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` methods do not execute and the return value from API is Null. But the request works correctly(I checked it using OkHttp). But other requests work perfectly. I tried running it using `execute()` but I had `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Here is my OkHttp part:

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new 
    HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();
            requestBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            requestBuilder.addHeader("Content-type", " application/json");
            if (SharedPrefs.isAuthorized(CApplication.appContext)) {
                String token = "bgbqdjsbfjsadnvas";
                requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", token);
            }
            requestBuilder.method(request.method(), request.body());


            return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
        }
    }).addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ClientConfig.BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    restInterface = mRetrofit.create(RestInterface.class);
```

Here is my Request:

```
M_Contact mContact = new M_Contact();
Call<M_Contact> call = rest.getAllContacts(userId);
call.enqueue(new Callback<M_Contact>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<M_Contact> call, Response<M_Contact> response) {
    if (null != response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) 
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Success: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else 
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something Happened: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
    }
    else Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<M_Contact> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
});

System.out.println("request finished");
```

Here is My build.gradle file:

```
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

Here is my LogFile:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.1.58:315/api/Main/RestoreContacts?userId=22 http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
D/OkHttp: Authorization: upktW1SlDkq0vbl5AjtQeA==
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.1.58:315/api/Main/RestoreContacts?userId=22 (541ms)
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: Expires: -1
D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
D/OkHttp: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 29 Jun 2017 06:55:40 GMT
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 842
D/OkHttp: {"userId":22,"contactList":[{"id":4589,"name":"gholam","phoneNumberList":[{"id":6148,"phoneNumber":"+989114514225","isPrimary":"","type":null}]},{"id":4590,"name":"karim","phoneNumberList":[{"id":6149,"phoneNumber":"+9821444","isPrimary":"","type":null},{"id":6150,"phoneNumber":"+9822444","isPrimary":"","type":null}]},{"id":4591,"name":"test1","phoneNumberList":[{"id":6151,"phoneNumber":"+98911791","isPrimary":"","type":null},{"id":6152,"phoneNumber":"+9815246","isPrimary":"","type":null}]},{"id":4592,"name":"hamid","phoneNumberList":[{"id":6153,"phoneNumber":"1564164","isPrimary":"0","type":null},{"id":6154,"phoneNumber":"+619111158","isPrimary":"0","type":null}]}],"contactCount":4,"phoneNumberCount":7,"userDevice":{"model":"Genymotion Custom Phone - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 768x1280","serial":"000000000000000"},"isCacheAvailable":false}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (842-byte body)
```

I Really Appreciate Any Kind Of Help. Thanks

**Update**:
For Wrapping up again, the request result is Successful, But, The Two Methods(`onSuccess()` and `onFailure()`) does not work. they don't even start.
I just updated the request part. it's like, after the `call.enqueue(...` line starts, it suddenly jump to the `System.out.println('...');` line without passing through the `onSuccess()` and `onFailure();`.

**UPDATE**

This is my Response Data Structure:

```
class M_Contact{
    public int userId;
    public List<ContactModel> contactList;
    public int contactCount;
    public int phoneNumberCount;
    public M_Device userDevice;
    public boolean isCacheAvailable;
}

class ContactModel{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public List<M_ContactPhoneNumber> phoneNumberList;
}

class M_ContactPhoneNumber{
    public int id;
    public String phoneNumber;
    public String isPrimary;
    public String label;
}

class M_Device{
    public String model;
    public String serial;
}
```

I Removed getter and setters and other methods for ease in reading.

Comment: is there any error in serializing `M_Contact`?

Comment: You problem is not understandable.  Post some logcat in detail

Comment: your log shows success, what is the issue?

Comment: @EricB. no i checked it it's fine

Comment: @MD, the only important log cat is which I posted them. Others are useless

Comment: can you share the `M_Contact` class structure?

Comment: @SripadRaj I updated the question

Comment: Everything looks fine, not sure what could be the problem. Please tell me why do you have `exclude module: 'okhttp'` in your gradle?

Comment: @SripadRaj I don't know Exactly. In a tutorial about Retrofit 2, the trainer said it's better to avoid the default OkHttp in retrofit and use the separated one. I'm sure that it's not caused by this because I had this problem in one project that had not excluded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's silly but I just solve the problem with changing the request Execution line. At first, request execute at the last line of `onCreate()` but when I removed it to the first line of `onCreate()`, it solved :|
if Any body knows why this happened, I will appreciate to let me know too.

Thanks!